# How to sort the grouped rows in AngularJS ui-grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

How can I sort the grouped rows in AngularJS ui-grid?

Like in the official [grouping tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping), in the demo grid, if I were to sort the balance column ascending, none of the grouped rows would change, but the sorting was actually taking effect on the rows under each grouped rows. Like the image showing below.

The question is, how can I make it work so that the sorting can work on the grouped rows.

[image]

I tried to set the groped columns' sort priorities to higher than 0, but that seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can add sort: {priority:1, direction: 'asc'} in your columnDefs

exp
$scope.gridOptions {

columnDefs: [

{ 
     name: 'Company',
     sort: {priority:1, direction: 'asc'}
   }
]

}

Answer (score 0):

May not be possible. Looks like a known limitation of ui grid

REf :https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3930

Note: Grouping leverages the sort functionality, allowing a user to change the sort order or use external sort functionality and have the resulting list grouped. **A column(s) that is marked as being grouped is always moved to the high order of the sort priority**, as the data must be sorted to permit grouping.